# Finding the Normal line to a plane

Tags: calculus, vectors

I feel like I am missing something here, but maybe someone can help me out :)

I was asked to find the normal line to the plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ that passes through the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

The equation I am seeing for the normal line is dependent on one of the variables. I think I am just forgetting how this works and then misreading what is in front of me.

Perhaps someone would be able to clear things up here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal vector to $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ is $\left(\begin{matrix}A\\B\\C\end{matrix}\right)$

So your line is defined by $\vec{x}=\left(\begin{matrix}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{matrix}\right) +
\lambda \left(\begin{matrix}A\\B\\C\end{matrix}\right),\ \lambda \in \Bbb R$

Comment: It's so simple! Why do you need the delta?